# The orientation of a line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is the **orientation of a line**?

I was always told that the arrows on the x-axis and y-axis in the cartesian coordinates system determines the orientation of those axis; I honestly don't know what does that mean.

Comment: See [Orientation : two dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry)#Two_dimensions).